# Finding the total variation of a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

We have $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by: $
\gamma(t)=\begin{cases} 
      e^{(-1+i)t^{-1}} & t\in (0,1] \\
      0 & t=0 
   \end{cases}
$

The problem is:

> Show that $\gamma$ is a rectifiable path and find $V(\gamma)$, the total variation.

If I'm not wrong, its derivative is: $\gamma'(t)=\begin{cases} 
      \left(\dfrac{1-i}{t^2}\right)e^{(-1+i)t^{-1}} & t\in (0,1] \\
      0 & t=0 
   \end{cases}
$

And so, $\gamma$ is continuously differentiable, hence a rectifiable path and $V(\gamma)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^1|\gamma'(t)|dt$.

But I'm stuck with the integral...

If $t>0$, $|\gamma'(t)|=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{t^2}e^{-1/t}$. So $\displaystyle\int_{0}^1|\gamma'(t)|dt=\sqrt{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^1\dfrac{e^{-1/t}}{t^2}dt$

And I don't really know how to find that integral.

Is this the better way to find $V(\gamma)$, though?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $x = -\frac{1}{t}$

Comment: Oh, what a fool I am. It is almost immediate... Thanks for your help.